# Existence of limit for values of $x\to a^-$

Tags: limits

If I want to know that the limit as $x\to a$ exists I have to make sure both the limit as $x\to a^+$ and $x\to a^-$ exist and are equal. What if I want to know that the limit of a function $f(x)$ exists for values of $x\to a^-$ (values of $x$ approaching $a$ from the left). Do I have to make sure both the limit as $x\to a^-$ and $f(a)$ exist and are equal? Why or why not?

EDIT: The problem below is how I got to this question.

Find all values for $a$ and $b$ for which the following function is differentiable.

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2+4x+1&\text{if $x\geq 0$} \\ ax+b&\text{if $ x<0$} \end{cases} $$

The function is differentiable for $x<0$ and $x>0$. For it to be differentiable at $x=0$ the following limit must exist.

$$ \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{f(0+\Delta x) - f(0)}{\Delta x} $$

The right-hand limit is:

$$ \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{\Delta x^2 + 4\Delta x + 1 - 1}{\Delta x} = 4. $$

The left-hand limit is:

$$ \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{a\Delta x + b - 1}{\Delta x} = a + b - 1. $$

So the limit exists at $x=0$ if $a+b=5$. Now, for $x < 0$ we have:

$$ \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = a.$$

So (and here is the question I asked earlier) for values of $x$ approaching $0$ from the left how do I check differentiability? Do I have to say $a=4$, since the limit at $x=0$ evaluates to $4$? If not, then I don't need $b=1$, which creates the possibility of the function being discontinuous (which in turn implies it is not differentiable).

Answer (score 1):

No. $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ does not have to equal $f(a)$.

One example is this function:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $x\geq 0$}\\
2&\text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}$

Then $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=2$ exists, but $f(0)=1$.

Update:
Check your computation for the "left-limit": you would need $b=1$ in order for the left-limit to exist. Hence correspondingly $a=4$.

Comment: That is not my question. I just added the problem that made me think of the question.

Comment: Check your computation for the "left-limit": you would need $b=1$ in order for the left-limit to exist. Hence correspondingly $a=4$.

Comment: Thank! You are right. It was just a computational mistake. What should I do about the post? Just leave it?

Comment: @henriq Yes, you can just leave it as such. I have updated my answer to fit your question in its present form.